# "Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.". SSIS Error

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, iis, ssis

From bids package executing successfully *(Manually)*

Executing ssis package from asp.net page when I tried to run by
clicking execute package on page am getting below error.

> SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR. An OLE DB error has occurred. Error
>   code: 0x80040E4D. An OLE DB record is available. Source: "Microsoft
>   SQL Server Native Client 10.0" Hresult: 0x80040E4D Description: **"Login
>   failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.**". SSIS Error Code
>   DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER. The
>   AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "STAGING"
>   failed with error code 0xC0202009. There may be error messages posted
>   before this with more information on why the AcquireConnection method
>   call failed. component "Lookup 1" (2791) failed validation and
>   returned error code 0xC020801C. One or more component failed
>   validation.

There were errors during task validation.

Comment: I assume you're using internal credentials to authenticate against the SQL Server? Does the IIS user have permissions to access the database?

Comment: To rephrase Ahhhhbisto's, what use is running the IIS App Pool for your website?  Does that user have credentials to log on to SQL Server and run packages? What authentication mode is your site set for? My shot in the dark guess is your IIS is set as a local user and when you get that resolved, you're going to hit a kerberos issue

Comment: Just a little expansion on what has already been said. It sounds like the SSIS package has a connection string which is based on Windows Authentication (Integrated Authentication). When you run it in BIDS you are running as yourself and probably have access. When you run it from IIS you'll be using a different set of credentials, IIS credentials, pass through credentials or some other credentials.

Comment: not using windows credentials. in my local machine it is working fine from asp.net page, after publishing in IIS am getting error

Comment: iis set for network service authentication,

Comment: success, now am able to run in from asp.net page also